# Where is SQL Server merge replication snapshot synchronization log location?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have an issue with SQL Server 15 -> 13 merge replication process. It got stuck locking MSsnapshotdeliveryprogress table. So I have to look into logs to be able to determine what is causing this, but hey! where are logs located?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer by myself and it is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/troubleshoot-tran-repl-errors?view=sql-server-ver15#enable-verbose-logging-on-any-agent

I've added

`-Output C:\Temp\OUTPUTFILE.txt -Outputverboselevel 3`

To merge replication agent, started agent ant it is logging now into that file.